# File not found error using MS SQL drivers in pyodbc on Synology NAS

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc, synology

I've been struggling with this issue for the past four days. I'm down to thinking hardware architecture, as improbable as it seems.

Goal:

- Grab HTTP data using requests.get
- Load dataframe
- Insert MS SQL Server running on Synology NAS via pyodbc

Result on Synology NAS:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.18.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Scenario:
I worked out the python code and driver issues locally on my Mac. It works perfectly end to end. Executing the py file goes to URL, gets data set, uses pandas to create a dataframe. The pyodbc import uses the MS SQL driver to connect to the SQL Server running on Synology. All's well.

Next step is SSH to Synology NAS and setup HOMEBREW (excellent how to here, big shout out Olivier Gerardin: https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/153781 )

Brew install Microsoft drivers, tried them all, from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-2017

All attempts end with failure:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib

I have verified all paths, tried creating symlinks and also copying the dylib file directly to the path in the obdcinst.ini.

To eliminate pyodbc to Synology as the issue, I setup a MySQL server and was able to change the driver in the same code and successfully connected.

I've also uninstalled and reinstalled Homebrew, MSSQL Drivers, pyodbc, even Python itself. I am at a total loss, out of ideas to try.

Comment: if you provide a minimum reproducible example ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) at the point where you are stuck, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: I highly doubt that your Synology NAS is running a version of macOS that will always work with Homebrew casks and kegs - and especially Microsoft's ODBC drivers. What is the output of `cat /etc/os-release`? You'll need to follow the [Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) instructions to install ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server (or maybe even V17) that's compatible with it. In my experience most NAS equipment is running some variant of BusyBox Linux.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion my problem is due to Synology's OS (not running MacOS on Synology, two different systems). Homebrew kegs works but not cask. os-release does not exist. But the clincher, attempting to run sqlcmd gives file not found. I believe that's due to missing 32bit gcc libraries, which I have not found a way to install. So I'm writing this off as a loss unfortunately.